# Can't save changes to file after modifying with OpenXmlSDK

Tags: c#, openxml

I have the following pseudo code:

```
Cell cell = GetCurrentCell() // I read using the SAX way in case this matters
cell.StyleIndex = 2;
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

The style indices in my excel file aren't changed after this code is executed. Is this expected? If not, where could the problem be? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a file that you are reading with OpenXmlReader. You have to write it from the beginning with OpenXmlWriter. Use OpenXmlReader to read from your file, change the values however you want and then write them out to a new file with OpenXmlWriter.

Remember to learn Excel's format well enough to not get corrupted files.